# Unknown method "setForeignKey" in CakePHP 3, even though it's in the documentation

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a simple application with just 2 tables `downloads` and `urls` in CakePHP 3.3.14

I have a foreign key `downloads.url_id`. The idea being that the application logs a series of `downloads` for a given `url` record.

So my association will be "urls hasMany downloads". I'm trying to define this as per their documentation https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasmany-associations

In `src/Model/Table/UrlsTable.php` I put

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->hasMany('Download');
}
```

I'm not sure if this even does anything as if I change 'Download' to something nonseniscal (e.g. `$this->hasMany('Downloadsdfsdsdfs')` it's not even giving an error.

However when I try and define the relationship like this: `$this->hasMany('Download')->setForeignKey('url_id');` it gives an error

**Unknown method "setForeignKey"**

Why is this? `setForeignKey` is a method given in Cake's documentation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is new method in 3.4 version that replaced foreignKey() from 3.3

You should use:

```
foreignKey("foreign_key_name")
```

Documentation: https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.ORM.Association.html#_foreignKey